Media Source Extension appending segments SourceBuffer has been removed from the parent media source error
I am trying to read segments from the backend and append them to my source buffer, but for some reason, I keep getting an error message stating that the source buffer has been removed from the source media.
Here is my code
if ('MediaSource' in window) {
                console.log('MediaSource works');
                let mediaSource = new MediaSource();
                video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);

                mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', async () => {
                    const sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'); // Adjust codec as necessary
                    console.log(sourceBuffer);

                    try {
                        await fetchAndAppendSegments(mediaSource, sourceBuffer, videoId);
                        if (mediaSource.readyState === 'open') {
                            mediaSource.endOfStream();
                        }
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error('Error during fetch and append segments:', error);
                        if (mediaSource.readyState === 'open') {
                            mediaSource.endOfStream('network');
                        }
                    }

                    // Attempt to start playback explicitly
                    document.addEventListener('click', function () {
                        console.log("Should play now.");
                        video.play().then(() => {
                            console.log('Playback started successfully');
                        }).catch(error => {
                            console.error('Error starting playback:', error);
                        });
                    });
                });


            } else {
                console.error('MediaSource Extensions are not supported in your browser.');
            }

And the fetch and append segments function:
   async function fetchAndAppendSegments(mediaSource, sourceBuffer, videoId) {
        console.log("Fetching and appending video segments");
    
        // Fetch video metadata to get total size
        const metadata = await fetchVideoMetadata(videoId);
        const totalSize = metadata.size;
        console.log('Total Size:', totalSize);
        const SEGMENT_SIZE = Math.min(512 * 1024, totalSize / 10) * 4; // Example segment size: 512 KB or 1/10th of the total size
        console.log("Segment Size:", SEGMENT_SIZE);
    
        // Create array of segment ranges
        const segments = [];
        for (let start = 0; start < totalSize; start += SEGMENT_SIZE) {
            const end = Math.min(start + SEGMENT_SIZE - 1, totalSize);
            segments.push({ start, end });
        }
    
        let segmentIndex = 0;
        
        // Process each segment sequentially using jQuery each
        $.each(segments, async (index, segment) => {
            if (mediaSource.readyState !== 'open') {
                console.error('MediaSource ended prematurely');
                return false; // Break out of $.each loop
            }
    
            const { start, end } = segment;
    
            try {
                console.log(`Fetching segment ${index}: ${start} to ${end}`);
                const segmentData = await fetchSegment(videoId, start, end);
                if (segmentData) {
                    console.log(`Segment ${index} fetched successfully: ${start} to ${end}`);
                    await appendSegment(sourceBuffer, segmentData);
                    console.log(`Appended segment ${index}: ${start} to ${end}`);
                } else {
                    console.log(`No segment returned for range ${start} to ${end}, stopping.`);
                    return false; // Break out of $.each loop
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(`Error fetching or appending video segment ${start} to ${end}:`, error);
                if (mediaSource.readyState === 'open') {
                    console.log('Ending MediaSource due to network error');
                    mediaSource.endOfStream('network');
                }
                return false; // Break out of $.each loop
            }
    
            segmentIndex++;
        });
    
        console.log('Final MediaSource readyState:', mediaSource.readyState);
        if (mediaSource.readyState === 'open') {
            mediaSource.endOfStream();
        }
    }
    
    

Then I have the fetch segment from backend function:
   async function fetchSegment(videoId, start, end) {
        const segmentUrl = `http://localhost:8080/videos/${videoId}/segment`;
    
        try {
            const response = await fetch(segmentUrl, {
                headers: {
                    'Range': `bytes=${start}-${end}`
                }
            });
    
            if (!response.ok) {
                if (response.status === 416) {
                    console.error('Requested range not satisfiable');
                    return null;
                }
                throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
            }
    
            console.log(`Fetched segment: bytes=${start}-${end}`);
            return await response.arrayBuffer();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(`Error fetching segment:`, error);
            throw error;
        }
    }

And these should do the actual appending of buffers:
    async function appendSegment(sourceBuffer, segment) {
        console.log('Appending segment...', segment.byteLength);
        if (!sourceBuffer) {
            console.error("No source buffer");
            return;
        }
      
        try {
            await waitForSourceBuffer(sourceBuffer); // Wait until the source buffer is ready
      
            // Check for buffer overflow
            if (sourceBuffer.buffered.length > 0) {
                const bufferEnd = sourceBuffer.buffered.end(sourceBuffer.buffered.length - 1);
                const currentTime = video.currentTime;
      
                if (bufferEnd - currentTime > 30) {
                    sourceBuffer.remove(0, bufferEnd - 30); // Remove old data if needed
                    await waitForSourceBuffer(sourceBuffer); // Wait for the removal to complete
                }
            }
            
            console.log('Appending buffer segment.');
            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(segment);
            await waitForSourceBuffer(sourceBuffer);
            console.log('Buffer append completed');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error appending segment:', error);
            throw error;
        }
      }
    
    function waitForSourceBuffer(sourceBuffer) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (!sourceBuffer.updating) {
                resolve();
                return;
            }
    
            const updateEndHandler = () => {
                sourceBuffer.removeEventListener('updateend', updateEndHandler);
                resolve();
            };
    
            const errorHandler = (e) => {
                sourceBuffer.removeEventListener('error', errorHandler);
                reject(new Error('SourceBuffer error: ' + e.message));
            };
    
            sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', updateEndHandler);
            sourceBuffer.addEventListener('error', errorHandler);
        });
    }

Here are the logs:

